# What is 'exhausted buffer' in gel electrophoresis?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

For gel electrophoresis of DNA, we use TAE or TBE. 
TAE buffer is cheaper than TBE but it has low buffering capacity; it exhausts faster than TBE buffer and there is a need to change the buffer during gel electrophoresis when electrophoresis longer.

but what is 'exhaused' in gel electrophoresis?

Comment: Do you have a source saying you need to change buffers during electrophoresis? I have never heard this and never seen any problems running gels longer.

Comment: Never heard of having to change the buffer during electrophoresis. When you turn down the voltage, you just throw it away. I would even think that replacing the buffer during the test, could produce errors and affect in a negative way the layers separated into the gel. Right now i do not have my labs notes under hand

Comment: OMG I heard about that where BRIC, Korean biologist community. ...I cannot believe there.

Comment: Then, what is 'exhausetd buffer' in gel electrophoresis?